# Django Forms and query limit of ModelChoiceField queryset

Tags: django, django-forms

Creating a form inheriting the "**forms.ModelForm**" class:

```
number = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Number.objects.order_by('?')[:6], empty_label=None)
```

The result is a **Choice form** is created, and random numbers limited to 6 entries will appear. But data indicating the limit is not accepted.
if you make the code like this without a limit:

```
number = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Number.objects.order_by('?'), empty_label=None)
```

Then all records appear in the form, and the form is validated everything is fine.

P.S

```
SELECT "number"."number" FROM "number" ORDER BY RAND() ASC LIMIT 6
```

When requesting a limit, the log shows that it works perfectly with **LIMIT**

I need help please

Comment: What do you mean by `data indicating the limit is not accepted` ?

Comment: string or text...

Comment: But it does't limit the queryset or there is an error raised?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the form makes 2 requests to the database, and validation fails because the server has a set of the 1st request and the client is rendered from the 2nd request.
Solved the issue by using the object call function.

Comment: Hi. I am facing **almost a similar problem** with [my query here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75564443). As I have explained there, my form submits when it is with all the fields' values. Howerer, attempting to generate a random set of object instances, it fails. Could you please explain how did you solve your problem?